# bokeh label does not support multi line

Tags: label, bokeh, multiline

Case: multi-line by `\n`.

I think the same modification to bokeh text required.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("text.html")

p = figure(x_range=(0, 5))
p.text(x=[1,2,3], y = [0,0,0], text=['hello\nworld!', 'hello\nworld!', 'hello\nworld!'], angle = 0)

label = Label(x=2, y=-0.5, 
text='label\nworld',render_mode='css',border_line_alpha=0.5,
                background_fill_alpha=0.5)

p.add_layout(label)

show(p)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2GLY.png)

Answer (score 0):

As of version `0.12.13` multi line text is only supported by the `text` glyph.  If you'd like to request it be added to `Label` please make a feature request issue on GitHub.

Comment: There is an open issue here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7317